# surface with rational curve in the double locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

I am interested in the existence of a surface $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with the following properties (or a reason for why one cannot exist):

- $X$ is slc (and not-normal)
- There is rational curve $C \subset X$ contained in the double locus (i.e. non-normal locus)
- The cotangent $\Omega^1_Y$ is ample, where $Y \to X$ is the normalization

Note that this last condition implies that $Y$ has no rational or elliptic curves. In particular, since the pre-image of the double locus under the normalization is a 2-to-1 cover branched over the pinch points, 
Riemann-Hurwitz gives that $C$ contains at least 6 pinch points.

The only examples I know of non-normal surfaces with a rational curve in the double locus containing $> 2$ pinch points have non-positive Kodaira dimension.

Comment: What does "slc" mean?

Comment: @Sasha slc stands for Semi Log Canonical singularities. It is a higher dimensional analogue of nodes for curves and it appears naturally in the study of moduli spaces of higher dimensional varieties (and pairs). More in detail is a non-normal version of log canonical singualirities, in which one requires the normalization to have lc singualirities plus other technical conditions. For a formal definition and properties see [Chapter 3](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~kollar/book/chap3.pdf) of Kollár's book.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~rollenske/papers/slc_hypersurfaces.pdf) you can see an explicit list of slc singularities in dim 2.

Comment: Thanks. So, if you find a genus 2 curve $C \subset Y$ and glue together the orbits of the hyperelliptic involution of $C$ on $Y$, will the resulted surface be slc?

Comment: @Sasha can you explain what you mean by "glue together the orbits of the involution of the curve inside the surface?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible example building up on what I think was the idea of @Sasha.

Take $Y$ to be a non-isotrivial fibration of genus $g_1 \geq 3$ curves over a genus $g_2 \geq 2$ curve that contains a closed fiber $C'$ which is hyperelliptic. Such surfaces (Kodaira fibrations) have ample cotangent.

Consider the surface $X$ obtained by the pushout of $Y$ given by the quotient by the involution, i.e.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    C' @>\sigma>> \mathbb{P}^1\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    Y @>>> X
\end{CD}

This is an slc surface $X$, and $Y$ has a finite map to $X$ that is birational and finite. Moreover one can show that $Y \to X$ is the normalization.
By construction of the pushout the image of the hyperlliptic fiber $C'$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ inside the double locus of $X$.

**Follow up question:** Is this surface contained in the closure of the main component of the moduli space of surfaces of general type (i.e. is $X$ a smoothable surface in the sense of KSBA)?